# How To Ensure consistency between common class and inherited class by newtonsoft.json.jsonconvert.serialobject

Tags: c#, json

I encounter a problem when I use Newtonsoft to serialize object,

when I serialize an object which is an instance of inherited class,for example:

```
class A
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class B：A
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

and the class C：

```
class C
{
    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

I use class B on server-side, and my customer on client-side because he only know which property have to be use,and we all use the same strategy logic to make  encrypted string . I found the order of serialized string is not equal: the B may be is `[A:1;B:2]` and the C may be is `[B:2:A:1]`, hope your help.

This is my test datas:

```
[
    {
        "amount":100.0,
        "memberId":75,
        "orderId":233,
        "projectId":233,
        "consumeNo":"6d1dd604b0844fa28b78380e5a05f1c1"
    }
]
```

and the customer give me his post data is :

```
[
    {
        "memberid":75,
        "orderid":233,
        "amount":100.0,
        "projectid":233,
        "consumeno":"6d1dd604b0844fa28b78380e5a05f1c1"
    }
]
```

You can see the account and memberid and orderid is not the same order, because he use C and I use B

At last I do it by using another method and the code below:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
               {
                   ContractResolver = new OrderedContractResolver()
               };

string listJons = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value,settings);


public class OrderedContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override System.Collections.Generic.IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(System.Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).OrderBy(p  => p.PropertyName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you concerned about the order in which your items are serialized? If so... you shouldn't. The order of entries in a Serialized object is not relevant, only it's ancestry. Are you trying to parse the serialized string in some way that is causing you issues?

Comment: hi i add the comment on question

Comment: The order of the items will not affect serialization and de serialization. So we need to understand what your are trying to do. Case sensitivity more likely to be a problem for you in the examples you have provided.

Comment: I want to take it as paramter to create md5 string code..

Comment: Ah right. That won't work consistently unless your objects are identical. If possible try making your md5 with a subset of the properties rather than the entire serialised String.